# Read connection string saved in file

Tags: vb.net

Good Morning,

How do I get `vb.net` to read that the string I'm passing is inside the txt file?

```
Public Const strConexao As String = "C: \ Users \ TestFile.txt"
```

Inside the txt file is the database:

```
connection string: 
Data Source = Test\SQLEXPRESS;InitialCatalog=BDTest;Integrated Security =True
```

I'm new to this and I can't make it run, I know it's a beginner's doubt.
How do I implement in this code a way to read the content in `"C: \ Users \ TestFile.txt"` and use it in my strConexao?

Comment: or have a look over [here](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @shahkalpesh i translated, thnk u

Comment: Check [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-read-from-text-files) out

Comment: @AConfusedSimpleton I've been looking at this. But I didn't understand how to implement the code there, I'm new to it.

Comment: @jackbauer, that's ok. Have you made an attempt? Edit your question to include what you tried and then people can have a look to see what went wrong.

Comment: IMHO *don't* store things like this in a plain text file, it encourages bad practice and will come back to grab you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio offers the things you need for this already. Add a new file to your project of type Application Configuration File from the add file option in Visual Studio (Add --> New Item --> Common --> General). In the new app.config, add your connection string. Add a Reference to your project, referencing `System.Configuration`.

**app.config Section:**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BDTest" connectionString="Data Source=Test\SQLEXPRESS;InitialCatalog=BDTest;Integrated Security=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Now, reference your connection string like this:

```
Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BDTest").ToString
```

You'll need `Imports System.Configuration` on the code page where you use the `ConfigurationManager` object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your text file has more than one line. One way to get the line you want is something like this:

```
Public Function GetTheLine() As String
    'A using block ensures proper disposal of the streamreader object for you
    Using SR As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\TestFile.txt")
        Dim Line As String
        Do
            Line = SR.ReadLine()
            If Line.StartsWith("Data Source", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                Return Line
                'if you find your line, then stop looking and return it
            End If
        Loop Until SR.EndOfStream 'loop until the end of the file
    End Using


    'function will only reach this point if the line wasn't found
    MsgBox("End of file reached with no results")
    Return ""



End Function
```

more documentation on streamreader can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.8)

there are of course other ways to do this. You will still need to work with the string to get just the part you need. you can start by looking at [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: `connection string: 
Data Source = Test\SQLEXPRESS;InitialCatalog=BDTest;Integrated Security =True` are we sure that `Data Source` is indeed on a line by itself; it maybe on one line...

Comment: That's true, i (perhaps falsly) assumed it was. I also (perhaps falsly) assumed there's only one line with "Data Source" in it.

Comment: As we don't know exactly what the textfile looks like it's hard to give an exact solution, just trying to help.

Comment: My file has only one line:

'Data Source =Teste \SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog =BDTest; Integrated Security = True'

Comment: It has only connection string for the database, as I want to use it for other users, each machine would have a file in the form of connecting to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Add Imports System.IO to the top of the file.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim conString = File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\TestFile.txt")
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(conString)
        'Your code using the connection
    End Using
End Sub
```